# Replacing HTTP responses from a specific URL in Windows

Tags: networking, proxy

I have some software which makes a request to a specific URL in internet and I want it to receive my custom response. Is there any software tool for that on Windows? Also it would be nice if I could map a regexp instead of specific URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

1. Set the domain of the URL to point to 127.0.0.1 in windows hosts file
2. Install nginx and set it up to show your file for the request response to which you're willing to modify and proxy all other requests to the original server

Answer (score 1):

Does [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) help you?

> Privoxy is a non-caching web proxy with advanced filtering capabilities for enhancing privacy, modifying web page data and HTTP headers, controlling access, and removing ads and other obnoxious Internet junk. Privoxy has a flexible configuration and can be customized to suit individual needs and tastes. It has application for both stand-alone systems and multi-user networks.

Comment: Thanks, but it only seems to work with browser. What I need is for it to capture all HTTP traffic in Windows so that I could manipulate responses on the top level.